# Log exception in database and displaying message on the page itself not on the custom error page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page and I want to log exception in database if an error occurs on the page1.aspx at button click or page load etc.
There are 2 ways

1. Log exception using global.asax Application_Error event, but this will not show a user friendly message on the page1.aspx instead it will redirect to custom error page.
2. Log exception at the page level i.e. Page_Error , but here I have to write code in Page_Error event on each page.

So my question is how to display user friendly message on the page1.aspx itself and loging error in global.asax Application_Error without redirecting to custom page/leaving the page1.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using httpModules. The link below will show you how you can write to a text file. Writing to a database wouldn't be so different.

http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/ASPNETHow-to-write-error-messages-into-a-text-file-using-a-simple-httpModule.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used `HttpModules` before, you may want to take an alternate approach.

Create a `subclass` of MasterPage, calling it something like BaseMasterPage. (or if you are not using a `MasterPage`, use `Page`).

Instead of your MasterPage code behind inheriting from MasterPage

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    ....
}
```

Inherit the subclass

```
public partial class MasterPage : BaseMasterPage
{
    ....
}
```

And place your error handling code in the BaseMasterPage.